# CSS Spacing is Wrong and Content Extends Beyond Container

Tags: html, css

Please bear with me. I'm new to coding.

I'm creating a web page. It has a desktop view, a tablet view, and a mobile view.

- In desktop view, the gray boxes should be on the same line with spaces between them.

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYOow.png)

- In tablet view, there should be 2 gray boxes with spaces between them on the first line, and the third box should be on it's own line.

[Tablet View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0m9P.png)

- In mobile view, each gray box should be on its line.

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SC0Q.png)

My questions are:

- For desktop view how do I get spaces between boxes 1 and 2, and boxes 2 and 3?
- For desktop view, when I go to Chrome developer tool and select the section elements, the gray boxes are not inside the container. The gray boxes extend below the container. However, when I go to tablet and mobile view and select the section elements, the gray boxes are inside the container. Why is that?

[Chrome Developer Tools - Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQvDg.png)

[Chrome Developer Tools - Tablet View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yHdW.png)

- For tablet view, how do I get the first 2 boxes to be on line 1, and the third box on line 3?

Thank you in advance!! FYI, see below for code snippet.

-Ian

```css
/**********Base Styles *****************/
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

h1 {
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Arial, cursive;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    background-color: gray;
    

}

p {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -27px;
    right: -11px;
}

section {
    margin: 10px;
}

div > section > div > div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

div > p {
    
}

#p1 {
    background-color: pink;
    
}

#p2 {
    background-color: maroon;
    color: white;
}

#p3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

/************* Desktop Devices Only ***********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-3 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    
    }

    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%      
    }
}


/********** Tablet Devices Only **************/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    #section1 {
        width: 45%;
        float: left;


        }

    #section2 {
        width: 45%; 
        float: left;                            
    }

    #section3 { 
        float: left;
    }

    }


/************ Mobile Devices Only *************/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-sm-12 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .col-sm-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
    <title>Our Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test-css.css">
    <style>
        
        /********* Simple Responsive Framework ******/
        .row {
            width: 100%;                    
        }   


    </style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Our Menu</h1>

    <div>
        
        <section id="section1" class="container">
            <div class="row">           
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">

            <div><p id="p1">Chicken</p></div>
            
            
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            

            </div>          
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div>
        
        <section id="section2" class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12"> 
            
            <div><p id="p2">Beef</p></div>

            
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            

            </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div>
        
        <section id="section3" class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            
            <div><p id="p3">Sushi</p></div>

            
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            

            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you suing a library as bootstrap? If so please tag your question the correct way. Last but not least, dont use `float` for stylign purpose. It should only be used for floating images within a text paragraph. I'm aware that it is commonly mis-used. However the modern approach should be the use of `CSS-Grid` or `Flexbox`.

Comment: PS: The main issue are the margins of your sections. If we think about the desktop view, then every section would be 33.3% + 40px wide (margin-left 20px + margin right 20px). So in total you would achieve a width of 100% + 120px and overflow the body by 120px. So you would need to use the calc function as example: `width: calc(33.3% - 40px);` in order to make it work. However I highly recommend you do go with a more modern solution as the css-grid solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the styling method to a CSS-Grid.

1st: I removed the margin of your sections: `section { margin: 20px; }`.

2nd: I wrapped all the 3 sections inside a div: `<div class="grid-wrapper"> ... </div>`

3rd: I deleted all your CSS within the media queries.

4th: I added following CSS for the `div.grid-wrapper` outside of any media queries: `.grid-wrapper { padding: 20px; display: grid; grid-gap: 20px; }`. This will create a spacing to the border of the screen of 20px (acts the same as your previos 20px margin). The `grid-gap` will keep the sections always exactly 20px apart from each other no matter in which media queries view.

5th: I added following CSS for desktop view: `.grid-wrapper { grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }`. This will divide the wrapper into 3 equal wide columns.

6th: I added following CSS for tablet view: `.grid-wrapper { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); } .section3 { grid-column: span 2; }`. This will divide the wrapper into 2 equal wide columns. The last 3rd section will span both columns.

7th: I added following CSS for mobile view: `.grid-wrapper { grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); }`. This way it will only be a single column and all sections are dispalyed below each other.

```css
/********* Base Styles ******/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS, Arial, cursive;
}

section {
  background-color: gray;
}

div>p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#p2 {
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
}

#p3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}


/********* Desktop Devices Only *******/

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 992px) {
    .grid-wrapper {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}


/*********** Tablet Devices Only **********/

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 768px) 
  and (max-width: 991px) {
    .grid-wrapper {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
    
    #section3 {
      grid-column: span 2;
    }
}


/************* Mobile Devices Only **************/

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 767px;) {
    .grid-wrapper {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <section id="section1" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-dk-4 col-mb-6">
        <div>
          <p id="p1">Chicken</p>
        </div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section2" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-dk-4 col-mb-6">
        <div>
          <p id="p2">Beef</p>
        </div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section3" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-dk-4 col-mb-6">
        <div>
          <p id="p3">Sushi</p>
        </div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Using `float` as requested. Note that it is an ancient and otudated emthod. Also a abd use in modern web development as `float` is not intended to be used for styling purpose but floating images within a text paragraph only.

```css
/********* Base Styles ******/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS, Arial, cursive;
}

section {
  background-color: gray;
}

div>p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#p2 {
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
}

#p3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}


/********* Desktop Devices Only *******/

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 992px) {
    .grid-wrapper section {
      width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3);
      float: left;
    }
    
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(1),
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(2) {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
}


/*********** Tablet Devices Only **********/

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 768px) 
  and (max-width: 991px) {
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(1),
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(2) {
      width: calc(50% - 10px);
      float: left;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(1) {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(3) {
      width: auto;
      clear: both;
    }
}


/************* Mobile Devices Only **************/

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 767px) {
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(1),
    .grid-wrapper section:nth-child(2) {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <section id="section1" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-dk-4 col-mb-6">
        <div>
          <p id="p1">Chicken</p>
        </div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section2" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-dk-4 col-mb-6">
        <div>
          <p id="p2">Beef</p>
        </div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section3" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-dk-4 col-mb-6">
        <div>
          <p id="p3">Sushi</p>
        </div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate the response. Thing is, I'm taking an intro class to HTML, CSS, and JS, and you've introduced some concepts that I'm not familiar with. I can only complete my assignment using the concepts explained in class so far. I made some progress. In desktop view, I have spaces between the 3 gray boxes. I put the section in a div and added margins to the div. How do I get the 3 gray boxes onto the same line with the basic CSS concepts that I'm using?

Comment: ok, well personal I think, that css-grid and flexbox both are basics. In fact they are pretty much the 2 major styling method for modern web development. Float is not only outdated /ancient btu also a completely wrong use. float should not be used for styling purpose. Its for floating images within a etxt apragraph only. However, for your assignment I will edit the solution with a float version.

Comment: if you need a further explanation on how to sue float or calculate the right width and margin just say so. In that case I will do futher edits

Comment: Hi. Still working on this. I decided to start over. I've updated my code in the snippet. I have all the boxes on the right lines. For desktop view, can you help me get space between the 3 gray boxes, while keeping them on the same line? For tablet view, can you help get space between box 1 and 2, keeping them on line 1? I can only use basic commands like margins, padding, border-box box sizing, float, etc. Thank you.

Comment: I've made more progress. Now I have all 3 gray boxes on the same line with margins between them in desktop view. Next I need to fix tablet view. I need to get the gray box on the second row to take up the entire row all by itself. I need to keep the other 2 gray boxes on row one with margins between them. Can you help? I've updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using bootstrap there but if you are, you're using classes that don't exist such as `col-dk-4` it's either `col-sm` `col-lg` and `col-md` and more, the full list is available [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#max-width) for your tablet view, for example, you can use col-md-6 on two boxes and col-md-12 on one box, which will make two boxes on the same line and the third on another line stretching along both previous boxes, just like on your screenshot.

If you are not using bootstrap, which is quite impossible since I see no grid or flex in your CSS, you must first define a grid, in your row class for example, with grid-template-columns set to repeat(3,1fr) by default (following a desktop-first approach here) and then on medium screens make it so that it's set to repeat(2,1fr), now select the third box in your CSS by its ID and set grid-column to 1 / span 2 which will make it occupy the entire new line, as in your screenshot, and on mobile, it's as simple as having grid-template-columns set to 1fr

This should work:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>Our Menu</title>
    <style>
        
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        .col {
            border: 5px solid #fff;
        }
        
        h1 {
            font-family: Comic Sans MS, Arial, cursive;
            text-align: center;
        }

        div {
            background-color: gray;
            width: 100%;

        }

        p {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100px;
            margin: auto;
        }


        #p1 {
            background-color: pink;
        }

        #p2 {
            background-color: maroon;
            color: white;
        }

        .row {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        }

        #p3 {
            background-color: yellow;
        }


        /********** Tablet Devices Only **************/
        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

            .row {
                grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            }

            #box-3 {

                grid-column: 1 / span 3;

            }
        }


        /************ Mobile Devices Only *************/
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .row {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Our Menu</h1>

    <div>

        <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">

                    <div>
                        <p id="p1">Chicken</p>
                    </div>

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>

                <div class="col">

                    <div>
                        <p id="p2">Beef</p>
                    </div>

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>

                <div class="col" id="box-3">

                    <div>
                        <p id="p3">Sushi</p>
                    </div>

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>


            </div>
        </section>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate all the help so far. I'm getting close. In desktop view, how do I get all 3 boxes centered on the same row? In tablet view, how do I get the gray box on the second row to be the same width as the 2 boxes on the first row? In all views, how do I get equal padding around the content? Right now there's too much padding between the labels (chicken, beef, sushi) and the top of the text. Finally, I think I used offsets and relative positioning incorrectly to place the labels in the upper right corner of the gray box. Can someone help? I've updated the code snippet. Thanks!

Comment: Have you copied and pasted my code? if I'm not mistaken it covers everything you mentioned, delete what you had and try the code in my answer and then tell me if something doesn't work or if you need something explained.